# Code igniter - mod rewrite issue

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have following kind of URL,

http://example.com/controller/method/VBGFrt543ERik4523/text1-text2

I want this to be shown in browser as,

http://example.com/text1-text2

I searched a lot but couldnt find any specific solution on this requirement.

Can anyone help me out please?

Answer (score 0):

Use URL routes with a bit of regex. This will reroute any url with letter and numbers followed by a hyphen and then letters and numbers to controller1/method/abc123/$1:

```
$route['([a-zA-Z0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9]+)'] = "controller1/method/abc123/$1";
```

(nb. you only can have one controller in your URL - it goes controller/method/variable1/variable2...)

You set routes in application/config/routes.php

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html

Good luck!

Comment: Sorry I didnt understand your answer. Can you please elaborate this?

Comment: I tried adding this in routes.php. It redirects correctly, but it doesnt recognize the id. $route['([a-zA-Z0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9]+)'] = "controller1/method/abc123/$1"; My id (after abc123) format is, 570458c5cb60aac9fbb001645c852e9c